# lualatex: includegraphics and image resoulution

Tags: graphics, luatex

I have an automated import of images into my LaTeX file which will finally compiled via luaHBTex 1.12. I want to include the images as they are but they shouldn't exceed the pagesize (neither height nor width). If they are larger they should be scaled automatically. Therefore I use the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
  Short test
\includegraphics[ max size={0.5\linewidth}{0.8\textheight}]
%\setkeys{adjbox}{dpi=96}
%\includegraphics[pxdim=1pt, max size={0.5\linewidth}{0.8\textheight}]
{images/myImage.png}

\end{document}
```

The usage of the package `adjustbox` works quite fine. My question is now about the dpi. As far as I see from the [luatex Manual](http://tug.ctan.org/systems/doc/luatex/luatex.pdf) (p.49)  the default value for `\pdfimageresolution` is `71` - which seems odd (Why not 72?). But anyway as far as I understand the `\includegraphics` uses 72 pixel per big dot (72bp). So now I have several options:

1. I can specifiy for all `\includegraphics` the specific size individually. E.g. for width of 48 px ==> `width=0.5in`. Here the question arises which is the 'best' unit to take?
2. According to the manual of `adjustbox` I can set either `pxdim` or use the keys for `adjbox`. But somehow they do not work. How to specify them correctly to work with `\includegraphics`? Especially when I want to use it for the whole document.
3. Is it a good idea to change the dpi resolution for the images in PDF? If so, how to do? Is `\pdfimageresolution`  the appropriate approach? And what's the value to set? `96` or `95` (to be in compliance with `71`)

So what is the best approach for the whole document? 'best' in sense of lualatex has the less work to do.